# Finding an element in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Does Java have a built-function to allow me to linearly search for an element in an array or do I have to just use a for loop?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a `contains` method for lists, so you should be able to do:

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourObject);
```

Warning: this might not do what you (or I) expect, see Tom's comment below.

Comment: Thats pretty short, but this use case is common enough that they really should have added a function into the language

Comment: Be careful not to use that with primitive arrays.

Comment: @Casebash It compiles but doesn't do what you expect. Because of evil varargs, the argument gets treated as an array of arrays of primitives.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981823/why-is-indexof-failing-to-find-the-object

Answer (score 16):

With Java 8, you can do this:

```
int[] haystack = {1, 2, 3};
int needle = 3;

boolean found = Arrays.stream(haystack).anyMatch(x -> x == needle);
```

You'd need to do

```
boolean found = Arrays.stream(haystack).anyMatch(x -> needle.equals(x));
```

if you're working with objects.

Comment: True, but if you're working with an `ArrayList`, doing `boolean found = haystack.contains(needle)` is much easier to read.

Answer (score 10):

Use a for loop.  There's nothing built into array.  Or switch to a java.util Collection class.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to consider using a `Collection` implementation instead of a flat array.

The `Collection` interface defines a `contains(Object o)` method, which returns `true`/`false`.

`ArrayList` implementation defines an `indexOf(Object o)`, which gives an index, but that method is not on all collection implementations.

Both these methods require proper implementations of the `equals()` method, and you probably want a properly implemented `hashCode()` method just in case you are using a hash based `Collection` (e.g. `HashSet`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the many [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) methods.  Keep in mind that the array must be sorted first.

Comment: That's an option only is elements of array are comparable themselves.

Comment: We can only assume that this is the case, e.g. an array of ints, Strings, etc.  You could always provide a custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort and search if needed.

Comment: hard to believe there's no Arrays.search ... <sigh>