# How to find the index of an element in an int array?

Tags: java, arrays, search, indexing

How can I find an index of a certain value in a Java array of type `int`?

I tried using `Arrays.binarySearch` on my unsorted array, it only sometimes gives the correct answer.

Comment: Binary search will never work on an unsorted array.

Comment: Then can you suggest me something, how should i do it. Because if i sort the array, i loose track of indexes, and i need to know which index the value came from??

Comment: EDIT: i forgot to add, i need to find array index for double values as well.

Comment: If you don't want to sort the array, just use a simple for loop to find the value.

Comment: It is generally good to read documentation of functions :) From `binarySearch`: "Searches the specified array of ... for the specified value using the binary search algorithm. **The array must be sorted** (as by the sort(long[]) method) prior to making this call. *If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.* ..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384203/finding-an-element-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: You need to have the array sorted to apply binary search.

Answer (score 147):

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(4);
```

Note that this solution is threadsafe because it creates a new object of type List.

Also you don't want to invoke this in a loop or something like that since you would be creating a new object every time

Comment: Thanks but would it work for type double?
Sorry i forgot to mention in the question, but i need to work this for double values as well. It works fine with ints though.

Comment: Yes it would, you don't have to change anything (but the array type obviously)

Comment: Actually the code doesn't work. Check [Why is indexOf failing to find the object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981823/why-is-indexof-failing-to-find-the-object)

Comment: You need to convert array to Integer[] instead of int[]. primitive arrays are not autoboxed.

Comment: Is this really threadsafe? When I click through the source the List.asList() creates an ArrayList that is taking the the int array directly as data container (not copying)

Comment: This will not work if primitive int type is a type an array.  In case of primitive array type, box it before using:  List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array)
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());   Then, Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(4); will give the correct index.

Comment: another use case, what if the array has two 4? mean like this {1,2,3,4,5,4,6} , how to get the both indexs fast and clean?

Comment: why can't we use `int []`

Answer (score 27):

Another option if you are using Guava Collections is [Ints.indexOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#indexOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

```
// Perfect storm:
final int needle = 42;
final int[] haystack = [1, 2, 3, 42];

// Spoiler alert: index == 3
final int index = Ints.indexOf(haystack, needle);
```

This is a great choice when space, time and code reuse are at a premium. It is also very terse.

Answer (score 19):

A look at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) and it says you have to sort the array first

So:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
Arrays.binarySearch(array, value);
```

If you don't want to sort the array:

```
public int find(double[] array, double value) {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
         if(array[i] == value)
             return i;
}
```

Comment: +1 However it should be noted that `Arrays.sort` *mutates* the input and the original array will be modified.

Comment: thank you, the 2nd method somehow worked me after adding some logic for duplicate values with different indexes.

Answer (score 16):

Copy this method into your class

```
 public int getArrayIndex(int[] arr,int value) {
        int k = -1;
        for(int i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] == value){
                k = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    return k;
}
```

Call this method with pass two perameters Array and value and store its return value in a integer variable.

```
int indexNum = getArrayIndex(array,value);
```

Thank you

Comment: If the value isn't in the array the original code returns 0, pointing to the first element in the array even though it doesn't match the first element.

I recommend rather than k=0, use k=-1.  If the value is not found in the array, this will return -1.

Answer (score 8):

```
ArrayUtils.indexOf(array, value);
Ints.indexOf(array, value);
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(value);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: 1) ArrayUtils.indexOf is what I'm looking for. 2) I don't know what Ints is. 3) Why would I want to convert to a list just to find an index? The code is easy, but terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 7):

You can use modern Java to solve this problem. Please use the code below:

```
static int findIndexOf(int V, int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                    .filter(i->arr[i]==V)
                    .findFirst()
                    .getAsInt();
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing. It helps to learn about the new (optimized) built-in solutions within the language capabilities context.

Comment: @Simplicity's_Strength Your edit was half correct, half incorrect.  Arrays do start at 0, but the [second parameter to `range` is exclusive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-).  Good catch on that first bug, though.

Comment: @RyanM That explains the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` i've had using this code.    Well played Sir

Answer (score 4):

You could convert it to a list, then use the indexOf method:

```
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(1);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: It is Arrays. ie Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(1);

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort values before using binary search. Otherwise, the manual way is to try all ints in your tab.

```
public int getIndexOf( int toSearch, int[] tab )
{
  for( int i=0; i< tab.length ; i ++ )
    if( tab[ i ] == toSearch)
     return i;

  return -1;
}//met
```

An alternative method could be to map all index for each value in a map.

```
tab[ index ] = value;
if( map.get( value) == null || map.get( value) > index )
    map.put( value, index );
```

and then map.get(value) to get the index.

Regards,
Stéphane

@pst, thanks for your comments. Can you post an other alternative method ?

Comment: This is one way, yes. However it is *not* the only way. The use of the boolean variable `found` here is useless (and not used) and should be removed. A +1 for showing "the manual loop method" though (stylistic and formatting issues aside).

Answer (score 3):

```
    Integer[] arr = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
    List<Integer> arrlst = Arrays.asList(arr);
    System.out.println(arrlst.lastIndexOf(1));
```

Comment: Note, array must be Integer[], not int[]. At least, indexOf() works only with Integer

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
public int getArrayIndex(int[] arr,int value) {
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if(arr[i]==value) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking for the answer-

1. You can use ArrayUtils.indexOf() from the [Apache Commons Library][1].
2. If you are using Java 8 you can also use the Strean API:

   ```
   public static int indexOf(int[] array, int valueToFind) {
       if (array == null) {
           return -1;
       }
       return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
               .filter(i -> valueToFind == array[i])
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(-1);
   }
   ```

   [1]: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf(int[],%20int)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to iterate. For example we want to find the minimum value of array and it's index:

```
public static Pair<Integer, Integer> getMinimumAndIndex(int[] array) {
        int min = array[0];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
                index = i;
            }

            return new Pair<min, index>;
```

This way you test all array values and if some of them is minimum you also know minimums index.
It can work the same with searching some value:

```
public static int indexOfNumber(int[] array) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 77) {        // here you pass some value for example 77
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of solutions here that are not working. The most upvoted solution used an array of **Integer**, instead of offering a solution to an **int** array. It is as simple as this:

```
Arrays.stream(yourArray).boxed().toList().indexOf(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 public class Test {

public static int Tab[]  = {33,44,55,66,7,88,44,11,23,45,32,12,95};
public static int search = 23;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long stop = 0;
    long time = 0;
    long start = 0;
    start = System.nanoTime();
    int index = getIndexOf(search,Tab);
    stop = System.nanoTime();
    time = stop - start;
    System.out.println("equal to took in nano seconds ="+time);
    System.out.println("Index  of searched value is: "+index);
    System.out.println("De value of Tab with searched index is: "+Tab[index]);
    System.out.println("==========================================================");
    start = System.nanoTime();
    int Bindex = bitSearch(search,Tab);
    stop = System.nanoTime();
    time = stop - start;
    System.out.println("Binary search took nano seconds ="+time);
    System.out.println("Index  of searched value is: "+Bindex);
    System.out.println("De value of Tab with searched index is: "+Tab[Bindex]);
}



public static int getIndexOf( int toSearch, int[] tab ){
     int i = 0;
     while(!(tab[i] == toSearch) )
     {  i++; }
       return i; // or return tab[i];
   }
public static int bitSearch(int toSearch, int[] tab){
    int i = 0;
    for(;(toSearch^tab[i])!=0;i++){
    }
    return i;

}
```

}

Added a XOR :)

Comment: `tab.equals(toSearch)` is comparing an array with an int.  Maybe `tab[i] == toSearch` instead.

Comment: This works thanks Mike... Google for binary search, some nice articles out there and its an interesting method

Comment: @Andre if you're trying to prove a point give them a level playing field (same order, same control flow): `while (tab[i] != toSearch) i++;` VS `while ((tab[i] ^ toSearch) != 0) i++;`.

Comment: In any case the this way of timing doesn't work, for me `bitSearch` is always faster than `getIndexOf`; while if I simply swap the calls to the two methods `getIndexOf` gets faster than `bitSearch`. This clearly demonstrates that the second one is always faster for some reason of JVM internals. You should be repeating the experiment many times (probably millions), averaging the values, discarding extreme values and doing a warmup that is very similar to the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Method to get the index of the given item from the list
     * @param stringArray
     * @param name
     * @return index of the item if item exists else return -1
     */
    public static int getIndexOfItemInArray(String[] stringArray, String name) {
        if (stringArray != null && stringArray.length > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
            int index = list.indexOf(name);
            list.clear();
            return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: The `clear` and the `new ArrayList` are unnecessary operations. Allocating a new `ArrayList` copies the whole array, which is pointless, because `Arrays.asList` already returns a `List` which has an `indexOf` method. Clearing the copy of the list is unnecessary, GC will take it away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the main method using for loops:
-the third for loop in my example is the answer to this question.
-in my example I made an array of 20 random integers, assigned a variable the smallest number, and stopped the loop when the location of the array reached the smallest value while counting the number of loops.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomIntegers[] = new int[20];
        double smallest = randomIntegers[0];
        int location = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.length; i++){             // fills array with random integers
            randomIntegers[i] = rnd.nextInt(99) + 1;
            System.out.println(" --" + i + "-- " + randomIntegers[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.length; i++){            // get the location of smallest number in the array 
            if(randomIntegers[i] < smallest){
                smallest = randomIntegers[i];                 
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < randomIntegers.length; i++){                
            if(randomIntegers[i] == smallest){                      //break the loop when array location value == <smallest>
                break;
            }
            location ++;
        }
        System.out.println("location: " + location + "\nsmallest: " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Code outputs all the numbers and their locations, and the location of the smallest number followed by the smallest number.

Answer (score 0):

**Binary search:** Binary search can also be used to find the index of the array element in an array. But the binary search can only be used if the array is sorted. Java provides us with an inbuilt function which can be found in the Arrays library of Java which will rreturn the index if the element is present, else it returns -1. The complexity will be O(log n).
Below is the implementation of Binary search.

```
public static int findIndex(int arr[], int t) { 
   int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, t); 
   return (index < 0) ? -1 : index; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static int[] getIndex(int[] data, int number) {
    int[] positions = new int[data.length];
    if (data.length > 0) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i] == number){
                positions[counter] = i;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 4) {
        system.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicated answer.