# Autoboxing not working?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have the following code:

```
static boolean nextPerm(int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        int k = N - 1;
        int[] S = { };
        while (k >= 0) {
            if (S.length > 0 && containsLarger(S, A[k])) {
                int v = firstLargest(S, A[k]);
                //int vIndex = Arrays.asList(S).indexOf(v);
                List<Integer> test = Arrays.asList(S); // // ERRORS HERE. Before error, S is { 2 } 
                System.out.println(test.get(0)); 
                int vIndex = test.indexOf(S);
                S[vIndex] = A[k];
                A[k] = v;
                System.arraycopy(S, 0, A, k + 1, N - k);
                return true;
            } else {
                S = addIntAscend(S, A[k]);
                k -= 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Before the error, S is an int array { 2 }. It errors when I set TEST to Arrays.asList(S):

```
Perms.java:44: error: incompatible types
                List<Integer> test = Arrays.asList(S);
                                                  ^
  required: List<Integer>
  found:    List<int[]>
1 error
```

Why is this happening? I thought primitives were autoboxed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4993464) which was closed as `Not an Issue` citing the below reason.

> Autoboxing of entire arrays is not specified behavior, for good
> reason. It can be prohibitively expensive for large arrays.

Therefore, to convert your array to an list, you need to do this

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>(S.length);
for (int i : S) {
    test.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primitives are autoboxed but arrays are not.
It will work if you change your int[]'s to Integer[]'s

Comment: But look at this example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6171675/2288418 He passes an int array to asList and is able to get the index of it.                 EDIT: Nevermind, there was an error in his example LOL.