# Java Finding index of an element in a java list

Tags: java, list, indexing

Simple question, but everytime I google it there are only examples using an ArrayList, and list.indexOf(3), doesn't work on int[] nums = new int[10]. Soo im a little confused.

Comment: And, the list consists of 10 elements. I was just writing int[] to show it's not an arraylist

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Iteration is `O(n)`, for a `List` or an `int[]`. Which do you have? Oh, and `Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(3)` works if `nums` is an `Integer[]`.

Comment: nums[***you're index here ***]

Comment: @mike The website you gave me tells me to use indexOf(object o), but  when I type it on my ide, it says. Cannot invoke indexOf(int) on array type int[]

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. That site was meant for lists, but you instantiated an array which is different.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the real problem.  You appear to think that

```
 int[] nums = new int[10]
```

is defining a `List` or a list.  It isn't.  It is an **array**.  The words "list" and "array" are NOT synonymous in the context of Java.  So when you Google for "finding an index of an element in a list" ... you don't get any useful hits.

If you use the >>correct<< terms when searching (Google, SO search, anything) you are far more likely to get useful search results.

For example:

- [How to find index of int array in Java from a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171663/how-to-find-index-of-int-array-in-java-from-a-given-value)

---

FWIW, if you want a (real) list of integers in Java you declare it like this:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
```

Notes

1. You have to use `Integer` as the type parameter, not `int`.
2. You don't need to provide `10` as a parameter.  And if you do, it is a hint that tells the `ArrayList` what the *initial capacity* of the list should be.  (For an array it is the actual size ... and it can't be changed).

Comment: ohh yea I thought it created a list with 10 indexes. Lame, alright I better find the difference between list and array thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use indexOf(3) on an array you could create a List from it

`ArrayList<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))`

and then you can use

```
myInts.indexOf(3)
```