# How to find array index value in android

Tags: android, arrays

I'm looking for a way to find the index position of arrays and i want to store that value in String but how can we do this please help me some one

### my arrayLists:-

```
  String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury","Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

 String[] Ruppes = new String[] { "100", "200","1000", "300", "400",
            "500", "600", "700", "800"};
```

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171663/how-to-find-index-of-int-array-in-java-from-a-given-value)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can do by using Arrays.asList

```
Arrays.asList(planets).indexOf("Mercury") // pass value

Arrays.asList(Rupps).indexOf("100") // pass value
```

or

```
Arrays.asList(planets).indexOf(2); //pass index
```

Comment: no it's showing eroors this line  String list =  Arrays.asList(planets).indexOf(position);

Comment: when i store that value in String there is errors are showing that line

Comment: i think we have to do here typecasting

Answer (score 4):

```
private int foundIndex(String query) {
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
        if (planets[i].equals(query)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

... in code:

```
        int index = foundIndex("Venus");
        if(index!=-1){
            String currentRuppes =Ruppes[index]
        }
```