# Does not print all elements in Array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I'm trying to get my array "numbers" to print out all even numbers for some reason I can't get it to call the array from earlier in my code so that the array can be used down below.

```
 import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){
      int numbers[] = new int [10];
      for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
      Random rand = new Random();
      numbers[x] = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
      System.out.print("" + numbers[x] + " ");
      }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("The values at even indexes are: " + numbers[0] + " " + numbers[2] + " " + numbers[4] + " " + numbers[6] + " " + numbers[8]);
    System.out.println("");
    if(numbers[x] % 2 == 0){
      System.out.print(numbers[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't get "called". You simply need to re-loop through the array in another for loop.

Comment: You can't use `x` outside the for loop. It is out of scope. You probably want this inside a loop anyway, to print all the even values, so you just need to wrap this inside a new for loop with `x` as the iterator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of int array in Java from a given value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171663/how-to-find-index-of-int-array-in-java-from-a-given-value)

Comment: Your array `numbers[]` is declared but not populated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem that you put `if(numbers[x] % 2 == 0)` outside for loop so you can't iterate over array by index `x`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
    if(numbers[x] % 2 == 0){
      System.out.print(numbers[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that keep the same values within the array?

Comment: yes the exact same values try it

Comment: It's giving me a line of output and repeating itself a lot how do I get one smooth answer.

Comment: just put `System.out.println(numbers[x]);` to print each value on seperate line

Comment: or put  `System.out.print(numbers[x] + " ");` to separate output with spaces in same line.

Comment: That may have done it. seems to be working at least thank you so much.

Comment: your welcome! hope it worked as expected.

Comment: accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I up voted it doesn't count cause my rep is so low.

Comment: however I'm trying to print the array as it is on a line then list values at even indexes on the next line then even numbers within the array on another line, my output is getting squished together on the same lines.. how do I get it to skip lines?

Comment: your right but if any answer solve your problem you can accept it by pressing correct button despite your rep .

Comment: oh I see now, sorry I'm new around here.

Comment: you can print indexes and values of even numbers in 
`System.out.println(x + " " + numbers[x]);`

Comment: I'm not having an issue getting the values it's when the output shows it's all disordered and I can't seem to get them categorized

Comment: check this program i organized your output as you want : https://ideone.com/RQp9TA

Comment: I was playing around with it and yes you nailed it exactly... My mistake was I was doing it all under one for loop instead of calling it again... Thank you so much Mohammad you've really helped me learn a lot.