# Why is indexOf failing to find the object?

Tags: java, indexof

I created an integer list and am trying to return the index of a specific value.
The array is 3,8,2,5,1,4,7,6 and I want to return the indexOf(3), which should be 0.

I've tried the following in the Eclipse Java Scrapbook after importing java.util.*:

```
int[] A = {3,8,2,5,1,4,7,9};
Arrays.asList(A).indexOf(3)
```

I have also tried:

```
int[] A = {3,8,2,5,1,4,7,6};
ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A));
l.indexOf(3)
```

Both are returning -1.  Why?  How to get this to work as expected?

Comment: Thank you for the answers everyone.  With that change though I would have to change my data structure, so instead I'll use the binarySearch method as it will work on int[] arrays.

Comment: Just be warned that that will only work on _sorted_ `int[]` arrays, which the examples you describe are not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't get your comment and the upvotes it got. `indexOf` "Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element." - so why wouldn't it  work for arbitrary arrays?

Comment: @arekolek I'm referring to @rishimaharaj's comment right above my comment, describing a plan to use `binarySearch`.

Comment: how to get the list of position if there is multiple data like there are multiple 3's in data?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be `Integer[]` not `int[]` in order to make it work.

```
Integer[] A = {3,8,2,5,1,4,7,9};
final int i = Arrays.asList(A).indexOf(3);
System.out.println("i = " + i); // prints '0'
```

Answer (score 36):

`Arrays.asList(A)` returns a `List<int[]>`.  This is because it expects an array of objects, not primitive types.  Your options include:

- use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`
- inline the array, and let autoboxing take care of it; `Arrays.asList(3,8,2,5,1,4,7,9)` will work fine
- use [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Ints.asList(int...)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList-int...-) method to view the primitive array as a `List<Integer>`.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)
- use Guava's `Ints.indexOf(int[], int)`, which works directly on primitive arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way

```
Integer[] array = {3,8,2,5,1,4,7,9};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);

System.out.println(list.indexOf(8));
```

asList returns `static <T> List<T>` Where T cannot be primitive (int[]).

Comment: how to get value at `index 0` on a *variable* `list`