# What is the best way to find a char index in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry for the title maybe this may seem like a dummy question. I'm new in java and assume I have a `char` array like this:

```
char[] hex = {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
    };
```

Now I want to find an item's index on that array for example `'a'`, but after some research I realized java's array class doesn't have an `indexOf` method. So I did the following:

```
int index = new String(hex).indexOf('a');
```

And it works fine, and after that I try following code:

```
int index2 = Arrays.asList(hex).indexOf('a');
```

It doesn't work and after I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981823/why-is-indexof-failing-to-find-the-object/9981855#9981855) question I understood the reason. But now I'm curious why finding an index needs too much effort in Java and why we can't get index directly? Why java's `Array` class doesn't have an `indexOf` method? Or is there an other simple way to do this and I'm missing it?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof

Comment: Thanks but asList doesn't work with char array,it returns List<char[]> I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options...

- You could use a `List` in the first place, which provides an [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
- You could keep the array sorted and use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29) (although perhaps this is overkill).
- You could (fairly easily) write your own function for this:

  ```
  public static int indexOf(char[] array, char key) {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
          if (array[i] == key)
              return i;

      return -1;
  }
  ```
- You could use a third-party library. Guava, for example, has [`Chars.indexOf()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#indexOf%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29). Apache has [`ArrayUtils.indexOf()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29) (which apparently deals better with null inputs).

---

For your *specific* array, since it has some nice properties, you could do this:

```
public static int indexOf(char key) {
    if ('0' <= key && key <= '8')
        return key - '0';

    if ('a' <= key && key <= 'f')
        return key - 'a' + 10;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,I know I can write my own methods, and this is the same logic of string.indexOf method =) I'm just curious why java's creaters didn't add a simple method like this?

Comment: @Selman22 You'll have to ask them, I'm afraid. There are many things that would be nice in Java but don't exist in the standard classes. That's why external libraries like Guava/Apache are very useful.

Comment: @Selman22 May you want to look at Apache's [ArrayUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html), specially the method `int indexOf(char[] array,
                          char valueToFind)`

Comment: @arshajii I prefer the method from apache instead of `Chars.indexOf()`, since it deals better with a potential `null` array as input.

Comment: @ZouZou thanks it seems fine but may I ask how can I import this library into my project ? I tried `import java.lang.Object` but it doesn't work I guess i need to download it but i couldn't find a download link

Comment: @Selman22 This is an external library, not part of the JDK. So you'll have to download it.

Comment: @ZouZou okey,I found now it was here [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `Arrays.asList()` is that it converts your primitives to objects (boxing) which may be expensive and memory inefficient.

If your array is not sorted, just write the indexOf method yourself:

```
public int indexOf(char[] hex, char value){
    for(int i=0; i< hex.length; i++){
       if(hex[i] == value){
         return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Of course if you really just want to convert to or from hex, there are much more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: @keshlam - yes, but I was answering the question of how to do Array.indexOf()

Comment: Thanks for answer @dkatzel, and yes I'm not trying to do some convertion,the char array is just for example