# Element in int Array is not found (while it should)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I don't get the correct index. Can anyone tell me why? I expect 0 as index, not -1.

```
int[] id = {R.id.buKeyPadNum1, ...} **(EDIT)**
int index = Arrays.asList(id).indexOf(v.getId());

Log.i("onClick", "v.getId "+ String.valueOf(v.getId())+" ButtonId "+String.valueOf(id[0])
+" Index "+String.valueOf(index));
```

LogCat:
09-25 08:11:32.039: I/onClick(1680): v.getId 2131296337 ButtonId 2131296337 Index -1

Comment: index `-1`  means it doesn't exist. `v.getId()`'s value doesn't exist in your array

Comment: how about `id.equals(v.getId())`, seems to make more sense

Comment: -1 means it's null and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Really? That is why i posted LogCat output. I try to find v.getId() in array id. id[0] and v.getId() are the same in LogCat....

Comment: well, perhaps data/object type is not the same

Comment: What data types are `id` and `v.getId()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(id)` returns a `List<long[]>`. `indexOf()` only works on `Long[]` objects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981823/why-is-indexof-failing-to-find-the-object).

Try using the `Long[]` type for `id`.

Comment: Yes "int[] id = {R.id.buKeyPadNum1, ...}" must be "Integer[] id = {}"

Answer (score 1):

Consider such code:

```
int ix = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2}).indexOf(1); 
// result: -1

int ix = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2}).indexOf(1); 
// result: 0  (found)
```

Probably your array contains elements with different type from indexOf argument.