# Equivalent to "in" for Java

Tags: java

In Python you can do something like

```
if 7 in list
    return True
```

Is there anything in java like this? To go "if x in array" without having to do a for loop or several lines of code?

Thanks

Comment: try using contains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: spend 2 seconds on Google before asking... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384203/finding-an-element-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384203/finding-an-element-in-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Java arrays don't have such properties, but you can either use a collection (preferable a Set, because the lookup methods are the most efficient) or wrap your array with `Arrays.asList()`

```
return Arrays.asList(arr).contains(7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray) - convert array to list
```

and then

```
.contains(7) - find value at list
```

Some other solutions:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2012/11/4-ways-to-search-object-in-java-array-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array  to list using [Arrays#asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)  and

There   is `contains()`  method in `List`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList class provides method `contains(Object)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Collection` `contains` method to check for existense:

`list.contains(7)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Commons Lang, there is [ArrayUtils#contains](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29).