# Attempting to compare two arrays with Arrays.contains Java

Tags: java, arrays, contains

I am trying to see if an element in my array is contained in one of my other arrays. I don't want to use a nested for loop for this and I am curious as to why my `.contains` does not work.

Currently I have two arrays

```
double [] s2 = new double [4];
double [] match = new double [s2.length];
```

and I am trying to test if `s2` contains any of the values in my `match` array

```
for (j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) 
        {
            if(Arrays.asList(s2).contains(match[j])){
                return true;
            }
       }
```

Does this have something to do with the double datatype I am using? If so is there a way I can still use `.contains`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30251235/1553851

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to use a nested loop?

Comment: You *are* using a nested loop, you're just using indirectly through `contains` (and you're creating a new list wrapper for `s2` on each pass).

Comment: Interesting I did not now know that  @chrylis, so would that give me a running time O(n^2) ? Because it would now be a nested loop running n amount of times.

Comment: You're wanting to check whether *any* element in `s2` is in `match`? There are some other alternatives with better big-O, such as sorting one first, but the constant will usually come down in favor of just looping twice.

Comment: [Implementation code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29), though simple reasoning will demonstrate that the best big-O of finding an element in an unsorted list is O(n), expected success time is n/2, and failure time is always n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the specific problem: `Arrays.asList` does not create a `List` of your elements but a `List` of only one value: your `double[]` of elements (at index 0). You should iterate through the list yourself for a second `for` loop instead of creating a different object.

---

It can be done with [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) operations ([java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)) instead of using loops, although the difference should be minimal.

```
DoubleStream.of(s2)      // Pipe the source array
    .distinct()          // Remove duplicate elements
                         // as they only need to be matched against once
    .anyMatch(value ->   // Consider if any value matches this condition
        IntStream.of(match)  // It equals any value in "match"
                 .distinct() // after removing duplicate elements
                 .anyMatch(matchValue -> matchValue == value));
```

For additional information about Streams - see these Oracle articles: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams [Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), [Part 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Arrays.asList(s2)` does not return a `List<Double>` object as you would expect.

It returns a `List<double[]>` object. So the elements inside that array will be of type `double[]`.

Generics doesn't work with primitive types well.

The solution is to convert the `double[]` into a `Double[]` somewhere.

Comment: As a solution, the user should use `Arrays.<Double>asList`.

Comment: @Unihedron Wouldn't work. asList won't accept the `double[]` that way. Compilation error :)

Comment: Ah you are correct, I was wrong for thinking the parameter would adapt. My bad!