# Multiple variables in If statement?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, if-statement

I'm fairly new to Java language and I'm having bit of problem.

I'm trying to make really simple Battle ships game. I have an array 3x3 filled with 0 and 1. 1 meaning there is a boat.

Every slot in the array is named n-n8. And I was wondering if there was a way of naming all the variables in one if statement.

The way I'm doing it right now is

```
if((n == 1 && x.equals("n") || (n == 1 && x.equals("n1") .. (n == 1 && x.equals("n8")){
System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")}
```

x is user input. You probably get the point.
So I would like to know if there's a way to shorten down the if statement or there's no other way. Something like :

```
if(n, n1, n2.. n8)
```

I tried looking it up but no success.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Note that your condition is equivalent to: `n == 1 && (x.equals("n") || x.equals("n1") .. && x.equals("n8"))`

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point.  Can you include the entire `if` statement?

Comment: For this task you need a loop. Something similar to what Mykota wrote in the answer

Comment: What else can x contain other than 'n[m]'? Shortest if statement would not check all names of array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of the eight names and use `contains`

```
if (n == 1 && Arrays.asList("n", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8").contains(x)) {
    System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")
}
```

This approach also happens to be null-safe.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you . I'm going to work on it now to improve it :-)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives:

Using a regular expression (works with Java 7/8/9):

```
if (n == 1 && x.matches("n[1-8]?") {
    System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")
}
```

Using the new Java 9 `List.of` convenience method (alternative to `Arrays.asList`):

```
if (n == 1 && List.of("n", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8").contains(x) {
    System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has no similar operators to those you mention. But you can rewrite your code using for loop:

```
for (String number : Arrays.asList("n", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8")) {
    if (n == 1 && x.equals(number)) {
        System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even better to use `contains` instead of loop

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("n", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8");
if (n == 1 && numbers.contains(x)) {
    System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")
}
```

Comment: You can use contains instead of looping through the list. `if (n == 1 && fields.contains(x))`. Making the list a constant static field might also be a good idea.

Comment: @MalteHartwig you are right! thank you, I've updated my answer

Comment: I'm going to try it right away ! Thank you for such a quick response !

Answer (score 0):

Mykola went right to the point, I'd suggest another option as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384203/finding-an-element-in-an-array-in-java):

```
if(n == 1 && Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8']);){
    System.out.println("Nice shot. Boat down.")
}
```

I don't have a jdk installed now to check it properly, but this is the ideia

Comment: It won't work. You can pass array as an argument only using new keyword