# How to verify if object exists in list

Tags: java

I am new to java I am trying to verify if the name exist in the list don't do anything else click to do some actions

```
        @Override
        public void accept(ExcelTestStep excelTestStep) {
            String[] names = attendeeTypes.split("@@");
            for (String name : names) {

                MouseOver.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Home.lnkManage);
                Input.run(Passkey_Events.ManageTab.lnkPasskeyAdmin);
                SwitchTo.run("xpath|//iframe[contains(@id,'menu')]");
                Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin.btnRegLinkSetup);
                SwitchTo.run("");
                SwitchTo.run("xpath|//iframe[contains(@id,'listing')]");

                Boolean blnObjPresent= clickObjectWithTagContainingText("option", name).isEmpty();
                 if (!blnObjPresent){
                     clickObjectWithTagContainingText("option", "All Organizers");
                     WaitForSeconds.run("200", "force");
                     clickObjectWithTagContainingText("option", name);
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin_RegLinkSetup.btnRegLinkContinue);
                     SwitchTo.run("");
                     SwitchTo.run("xpath|//iframe[contains(@id,'listing')]");
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin_RegLinkSetup.btnSave);
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin_RegLinkSetup.chkEnableParticipantAPI);
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin_RegLinkSetup.btnSave);
                     SwitchTo.run("xpath|//iframe[contains(@id,'menu')]");
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin.btnRegLinkSetup);
                     SwitchTo.run("");
                     SwitchTo.run("xpath|//iframe[contains(@id,'listing')]");
                     VerifyExistence.run(By.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'" + name + "')]"));
                 }else {
                     Input.run(Passkey_Events.PK_Admin.btnRegLinkSetup);
                       }
            }
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Comment: [How to Find an Element in a List with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java), [Finding an element in an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384203/finding-an-element-in-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

[Contains documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

Use the "contains" method.

```
if(someList.contains("Some text"){
    // do something
}
```